# How can I select the games from a backup drive to restore on Steam?

Tags: steam

I have a USB drive with CSGO, Portal, Portal 2, half life 2 on it, and I own all the games. I put in the drive and do the usual, but it's asking fora CD key. That's because there's a game in there that I don't own, but I own all the others. What can I do?

Comment: Can you remove the game that you do not own? And why do you have an unowned game on your USB?

Comment: It's my friend's usb, he has a bunch of games backed up

Comment: You and your friend are sharing a USB drive to back up each of your separately owned games?  Why don't you each just get your own USB drive?  Also, regarding the games you do own, why don't you have a CD key for them?

Comment: Basically I have a 2Mb/s internet connection and it will take very long to download all those games. He came from the US with all those games since he has a 180 Mb/s internet speed. I just bought all the games, so I don't think I can get the CD key

Answer (score 1):

- Open Google and type App ID "game name". This will be the game you do
  not own (e.g. Dota 2 would be "570").
- Go to the backup directory and open "sku.sis" in Notepad.
- Scroll sideways until you reach the section where it says "Apps".
- Look inside the brackets for the App ID in question. The first number will indicate the listing number off the backup and the 2nd the App ID. (e.g. "0" or "570").
- Delete the index number and App ID of the game in question (e.g. "0" or "570").
- Save and close Notepad and try restore from backup again.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the game you don't own onto different storage or your SSD if you have space. For example, I have Tales of Zesteria (but I don't own it on Steam) installed on my SSD and everything else that I own on my external hard drive. Also, do not import the non-owned game into Steam, otherwise, it won't run (for obvious reasons).